# ios-driver or Appium on Microsoft products

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, selendroid

I have depth knowledge in automation testing and Selenium 2.0 (C#), and
I'm new in Mobile automation test,
I need to decide which tool will be more intuitive and stable using Microsoft environment (windows operating system and visual studio), Appium Or Selendroid and ios-driver?
Second do you know if JAVA and OSX is mandatory when using Appium or ios-driver?

waiting for your feedback,

Thanks
Eyal

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are going use it for just Android then i would suggest to go for Selendroid but if you are looking forward for both iOS and Android then go for Appium.

Comment: I need both of drivers, but is Appium can run IPhone driver on Microsoft operation system and .Net? or i have to use JAVA?